# how do we input and save values to ArrayList thorugh setter method in java

Tags: java, arraylist, input, getter-setter, setter

This is the setter method for arraylist but dont know how to input through scanner and set the values thorugh this

```
ArrayList<String> itemNAME;   //Declaration of arrayList

public void setItemNAME(ArrayList<String> itemNAME) {
    this.itemNAME = itemNAME;
```

and in the other class this is the object

```
itemNAME = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Comment: First add the names in the other class. Then call the setter. Or, call the setter and then add the names. `itemNAME.add("Usama");` etc.

Comment: You get a list of strings and pass it to `setItemNAME`. Which should be called `setItemNames` since it's plural, and unless you *explicitly* require an `ArrayList` you should accept a generic `List`, noting that there are valid reasons to enforce an `ArrayList`. Alternatively, in the class with this setter, encapsulate the list and expose a method called `addName` which adds a string to the list.

Answer (score 0):

Class 1:

```
ArrayList<String> itemNAME;   //Declaration of arrayList

public void setItemNAME(ArrayList<String> itemNAME) 
{
    this.itemNAME = itemNAME;
}

public void addItemName(String item)
{
    this.itemName.add(item);
}
```

From there you can call `addItemName` whenever you need to add an item.

For instance, when you need to add from a scanner, you could store the input from the scanner into a temporary string and then in the next line call `addItemName` to add the string to your list.